# Ajax call returning users error: length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am making use of an ajax call to my controller that returns an array of around 10k users back to my view, which is used for pinning users. However, I am getting this error.

I have read up on a lot of posts and have see the following, and tried it, but still getting the same issue:

Tried adding the below into my web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength = "2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I have also added this to my actionresult:

```
var objJSS = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };

return Json(objJSS.Serialize(pinnedUsers), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Below is my entire `actionresult`:

```
public ActionResult GetPinnedUsers()
        {
            clsComments clsComments = new clsComments();
            PinnedUsersViewModel[] pinnedUsers;

            pinnedUsers = clsComments.GetPinnedUsers();

            //var jsonResult = Json(pinnedUsers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

            var objJSS = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };

            return Json(objJSS.Serialize(pinnedUsers), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Below is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPinnedUsers", "ILearn")',
        success: function (usersArray) {
                                    success(usersArray)
                                 },
                                error: error
                            });
```

Am I doing something incorrect or missing something ? Or is there another way of getting all the users passed to my view ?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Aside from the issue, returning that much data to the UI seems like a really bad idea. I'd suggest avoiding the issue entirely by finding a way to return a more filtered dataset, either by using paging or filtering

Comment: I actually do agree with you, I am just afraid that it may hinder performance, by having to load the whole list everytime a user typed in a specific letter of the users name to find them in the list.

Comment: That would depend on your datastore performance, but I'd be very surprised if it's slower. With the correct indexes setup it should be faster.

Comment: True that. I will see what I can do. I was hoping there was another way, but what you are saying does make me think it may be a pretty bad idea with so much data being passed back. I will let you know about performance once I have found the solution. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to find a solution to my problem. Thanks to this link: [HANDLING LARGER JSON STRING VALUES SERIALIZATION IN MVC](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/handling-larger-json-string-values-serialization-mvc/)

Below is the code I used:

```
        public ActionResult GetPinnedUsers()
        {
            clsComments clsComments = new clsComments();
            PinnedUsersViewModel[] pinnedUsers;

            //JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; //Or any size you want to use, basically int maxValue is 2GB, you shouldn't need this big json string to deserialize, else you are doing it wrong.

            pinnedUsers = clsComments.GetPinnedUsers();

            return SerializeJSON(pinnedUsers);
        }

        private ContentResult SerializeJSON(PinnedUsersViewModel[] users)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            var resultData = users;

            ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
            result.Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData);
            result.ContentType = "application/json";

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; //Or any size you want to use, basically int maxValue is 2GB, you shouldn't need this big json string to deserialize, else you are doing it wrong.
myObject obj = serializer.Deserialize<myObject>(yourJsonString);`

you can try this when you try to deserialise the JSON string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Serialize and deserialize is all still new to me. So if I am trying to pass a model(of type array) back to my view, do I return the deserialized data, or the serialized data ? Also, the "myObject" that you are using, would that be my model ?